# Why is my image not animating when I use CASpringAnimation?

Tags: swift, xcode

I would like my image to animate when it is being tapped on, this is my code so far, nothing happens for some reason when I tap on the image.

```
lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "made")
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(taptap)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return imageView
}()

@objc func taptap() {
    let pulse = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    pulse.duration = 0.6
    pulse.fromValue = 0.95
    pulse.toValue = 1.0
    pulse.autoreverses = true
    pulse.repeatCount = 2
    pulse.initialVelocity = 0.5
    pulse.damping = 1.0
    layer.add(pulse, forKey: nil)
}
```

Comment: Where are you adding CASpringAnimation to your imageView ? where is layer defined which is used in taptap function ?

Comment: How do I add a CASpringAnimation to my imageview, I don't think I've done that

Comment: taptap function is getting called when you tap on it ?

Comment: Yes taptap is called when I tap on the image view

Comment: try to add this line : profileImageView.layer.add(pulse, forKey: nil) instead of layer.add

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much I can't believe I didn't see that!

Comment: If you want to post your solution as the answer I will mark it with a check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine except the adding animation to `ImageView` line. Replace this line :

```
layer.add(pulse, forKey: nil)
```

with :

```
profileImageView.layer.add(pulse, forKey: nil)
```

You need to add `Core Animations` to `layer` of your view, here it is your `profileImageView`.